# I intend to put into practice some of the techniques ..... in the seminar

Tags: sentence-meaning, post-modifier

Which option fits best the followings question?

> I intend to put into practice some of the techniques ..... in the
>   seminar.
>
> A. Supported
>
> B. Expresses
>
> C. Advocated
>
> D. Performed

---

For me B and D looks ok.They all have very close sense.

Comment: Techniques are rarely "performed", they are "explained", "demonstrated", "applied", etc.

Comment: I would say "I learnt in the seminar" and not those sickly expressions suggested.

Answer (score 2):

A. Not appropriate; "by" would be the correct preposition to use with "supported"

B. Not appropriate; wrong verb form. "Expressed" would work, but doesn't quite fit with "techniques". (See Victor's comment)

C. This works.

D. This fits, but awkwardly. Something you "perform" must be concrete: a play, an act of kindness, etc. A technique is a method or way of performing. E.G. you could perform a play using the method acting technique.

Comment: I upvoted this answer, though *supported in* is a possible "appropriate" usage; and also to say that "advocated" seems not the best word to use; and thus that the choices all seem poor.

Comment: do you advocate a technique, I mean for me advocate implies a sense you try to vindicate an issue that some people don't agree with you..but in  a seminar you just teach/learn a method/ technique like CPR ..this is what I get the word advocate

Comment: To advocate means to promote. In a seminar, I might advocate using a blanket stitch for finishing quilt edges. I.E. I would tell people why I thought it was a good idea and perhaps demonstrate how to do it and why its results are better than... top stitching.